# Lottery variance

Tags: probability, variance, lotteries

The chance to win in Lottery game is $0.1$. Michael decided to buy a ticket every week until he will win or until he will buy 5 tickets.
if X is the number of weeks Michael bought a lottery ticket,
what is the variance of $X$?

So I Calculated for X=5, which means LLLLL or LLLLLW. I calculated the probabilities for both, added them up together and then calculated the variance by the formula  $\frac{1-p}{p^2}$. I get $0.798$ which I'm not sure makes sense, am I doing something wrong? Do I need to compute all weeks? Because if so, in the end I get 1.

Comment: $(p-1)/p^2$ is negative! It should be $(1-p)/p^2$ for the variance of a geometric distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that $X$ does not have a geometric distribution, precisely because you have the extra condition that $X \leq 5$. e.g. A geometric distribution would have $\mathbb{P}(X = 6) > 0$, but clearly $X$ can never be 6.

So $X$ is a discrete random variable that takes values in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Let $Y$ be a geometrically distributed random variable with $p = 0.1$. If $k \leq 4$, then $X$ is behaving geometrically, i.e.
$$
\mathbb{P}(X = k) = \mathbb{P}(Y = k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p
$$
But we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(X = 5) = \mathbb{P}(Y \geq 5).
$$
Can you see now how to proceed computing statistics for $X$?

Comment: SO I just take to probability of X=5 which is to lose 5 times $(0.9)^5$ or to win in the last week $(0.9)^4*(0.1)$, sum them up and from that I take the variance?

Comment: Yes, if I understand what you're asking correctly. To put it another way, we get $X=5$ precisely when there are 4 losses...

Answer (score 0):

Variance in Geometric distribution is $\frac{1-p}{p^2}$. The problem is, it is for infinite number of trials. In your case it is limited by 5, so you need to compute a normalizing constant, so that the probability distribution sums to 1. Once you've done that, you can compute its mean and variance using the formulas you know.